# Highcharts - How to have multiple datapoints per xAxis label?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highchart's graph that is displaying data from 2001 - 2020 in my array of data i'd like to assign xAxis point `2001` the first 4 indexes of my array which are `2.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3`, have 2002 have the next 4 points etc, with keeping my xAxis categories label in tact.

At the moment because I have more data points then labels my xAxis labels eventually get cut off and HighCharts start to add numbers to the bottom of the graph.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pqxvguet/2/)

Here is a photo example:

[image]

I am attempting to have the xAxis at the bottom show what I assigned it :

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020']
  },
```

meanwhile having more then one point per year. I hope that is clear, and I am stuck on how to accomplish that in HighCharts, as I add more data the graph continues to expand with the numbers on the bottom instead of the years I am expecting.

I am expecting my Highcharts graph xAxis to appear like this [image]

while having more than one data point per label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pointStart` feature to achieve wanted result.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wgr253pf/

```
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      enableMouseTracking: false,
            pointStart: 2001
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart

Comment: thank you for your response, in the jsfiddle example you provided is there a way to end the date on 2020? like a `pointEnd` so to speak? I tried applying that to the code and it ended up starting my data at `2020` instead of `2001`

Comment: There is no such option. The endpoint depends on your data. However, you should be able to achieve a similar result base on the `pointInerval` option and your data array length. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointInterval